# Netzke / ExtJS 4 - How to implement Dynamic number of Panels inside an Accordion Panel

Tags: netzke

I am trying to read strings off a table in the database and use them as titles in panels inside an accordion panel.
In short the number of panels inside the accordion can change dynamically.

Here is a gist of what i tried - https://gist.github.com/1199695. I get the names from the table with an endpoint in my Ruby class. The returned data contains a string for the client JS function (named addPanel) which is called to add the Panel inside the accordion.

The code executes as i expected but the panels inside the accordion do not show up.

My suspicion is that the rendering is happening before the items get into the accordion.

If i hard code the addition - via class_name.items.add(new Ext.panel.Panel({:title "My panel"}) ) inside the initComponent then i can see the panel titled "My panel" inside the accordion.

Let me know if this is the correct way to approach the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need the accordion panes to be Netzke components? If not, then you could try out something like:

```
 def configuration #:nodoc:
    super.merge({
       # ...

       :items => some_model.all.map{|item| {:item => item.title}}
    })
  end
```

Briefly, you just provide your Ext.tab.Panel-based class with the dynamic items configuration (taken from the model).